Linearity of expectation for infinite sums of positive random variables
I have a question regarding the linearity of the expectation of the infinite sum of positive random variables, namely I want to prove on a countable space $\Omega$ that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[X_n] 
\end{equation}
for $X_n \geq 0$ and both sides might be equal to $\infty$.
Now, doing some research it seemed to be reasonable to somehow use Fubini in order to switch the integrals (interpreting the sum as an integral with discrete measure) but I seem to lack the ideas to give it a rigorous proof.
Any hints that get me going would be much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Suppose $X_i$ are nonnegative random variables for all $i\in\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.
For one direction, fix $m$ as a positive integer, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n\geq \sum_{n=1}^mX_n\implies E\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n\right]\geq \sum_{n=1}^mE[X_n]$$ so take $m\rightarrow \infty$ gives $E[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n]\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E[X_n]$.
For the other direction, you can use Fatou's lemma with the nonnegative random variables $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$:
$$ E\left[\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right] \leq \lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty} E\left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right]$$

Considering that the target domain is $\mathbb{R}\cup {\infty}$ can I assume that lim exists and then use your second part with Fatou?

Or is the explanation more basic in the sense that it is a sum of non negative random variables so $lim inf = lim sup$?

Yes, since $X_i\geq 0$, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is nondecreasing with $n$ and has limit $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$ (which is the same as the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ and is possibly $\infty$). The equation $E[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}E[X_i]$ allows the possibility of $\infty=\infty$.

Taking this into account couldn't I directly use Fatou twice (with liminf and limsup) to arrive at $\mathbb{E}[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n X_i]=\mathbb{E}[\liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum^n X_i]\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\sum^nX_i]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[\sum^nX_i]\leq\limsup \mathbb{E}[\sum X_i]\leq \mathbb{E}[\limsup\sum X_i] =\mathbb{E}[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i]$

I'm not sure what you mean by using Fatou with $\limsup$ (I would only use it with $\liminf$). Perhaps you mean what is called "reverse Fatou" on the linked Wikipedia page, but that would require  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i$ to have finite expectation (it seems to require a  bounding function similar to Lebesgue dominated convergence). I think separating into the $\leq$ and $\geq$ parts is conceptually easier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma

You might consider two (four?) cases.
(1,2) Suppose one side diverges, i.e. for all $R\in \mathbb R$ there exists $N$ such that $\mathbb E\big[\sum_{n=1}^NX_n\big]\geq R$. Then argue $\sum_{n=1}^N\mathbb E[X_n]\geq R$. This works in the other direction as well.
(3,4) On the other hand suppose $L\in \mathbb R_+$ and for all $N\in \mathbb N$, $\mathbb E\big[\sum_{n=1}^NX_n\big]\leq L$, yet for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $\mathbb E\big[\sum_{n=1}^NX_n\big]\geq L-\epsilon$. Can you finish from here?

Appreciate your answer, but I think the accepted one quite has a quite straight forward approach :)
